# How to connect pyobc to SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, database-connection

Hi I am trying to connect pyodbc to a flat file, ODBC database I have. I can see in the ODBC datasource administrator that the SQL Server driver is installed. I've never attempted to connect to a server with python before. I know that I am able to connect to this server through Excel (VBA Script) with no issues. The error that I get with pyodbc is:

> "pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
>       pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
>   (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (2)')"

I am not sure if I am just calling the connect function incorrectly (with the wrong information as the parameters) or if I am just getting access denied from the server. Like I said, I can connect to the server via Excel VBA script with no issue but I'm not sure if that means I should be able to connect with pyodbc. My code is below. I am copying and pasting the values from the ODBC admin to the connection string.

Is there a way to see if I am connecting correctly or not?

Is there a way to get a more detailed error to understand if it is an access issue or if I am just feeding the connect function the wrong info?

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=servername.com;'
                      'DSN=dsn;')
```

Comment: Could you show us the VBA? It's possible you're just doing something stupid, but there might be a real difference in functionality that needs to be made up to make Python talk to the database in the same way as VBA.

Comment: Also how are you expecting to connect as your connection string has no username or password - are you expecting to connect via Windows Authentication? The instance name you're posting 'servername.com' looks wrong for a SQL Server instance name as well.